# Variable value not supported problem, python

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi could anyone help with this += problem, please?

```
loss += total_variation_weight * total_variation_loss(combination_image)
```

error

```
RuntimeError: Variable += value not supported. Use variable.assign_add(value) to modify the variable value and variable = variable + value to get a new Tensor object.
```

How do you just replace the `+=` with an `assign_add()` call?

Comment: have you tried `loss.assign_add(total_variation_weight * total_variation_loss(combination_image))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
loss.assign_add(total_variation_weight * total_variation_loss(combination_image))
```

The problem is that `loss` is a Tensor object and not a regular numeric Python variable. Some things that work on regular numeric variables don't work on Tensors.

In this case, it comes down to value vs identity. With numbers, value *is* identity. That is, if you assign `x = 1`, and then do `x += 1`, the intent is clear, and there's no concern that you have somehow transformed the number 1 into the number 2 globally. You've just changed the number that `x` "contains".

With objects, you have the option. Do you modify the existing Tensor object so that it has a new value, or do you make a new Tensor object out of the new value? Pure functional design requires the latter, but Python permits the former; which one you should choose depends on other aspects of the problem you're solving.

So just like the message says: if you want to keep the same Tensor object but change the value it represents, use the `.assign_add` method. If you want to make a new Tensor object, use this instead:

```
loss = loss + total_variation_weight * total_variation_loss(combination_image)
```